# Directory.GetFiles not returning expected data when using pattern

Tags: c#, file-io

I am using `Directory.GetFiles` to return some files using a criteria, the format of the file names are "1digitnumber_number_number.jpg", I want to return only those files which are named like "any1digitnumber_numberstartingwithzero_anynumber.jpg", an example would be "3_012_12312.jpg"

The code I am using to return this is

```
List<string> files = new List<string>(Directory.GetFiles(@"c:\myDir","?_0*"));
```

Why does this code return values which don't even have a zero in them at all and none that actually fit the pattern?

**NOTE: My directory does not contain the syntax I am looking for**

Comment: Which files it returns with `"?_0*"` other than you expect?

Comment: @Sinatr it returns files like "1_547_13945.jpg"

Comment: Not able to reproduce your problem, however that pattern returns any file that starts also with a single letter not just digits.

Comment: Why are you loading the resulting array into a List?

Comment: @Steve that's interesting, they all have numbers though

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I was originally putting it into a list without the criteria and then using linq to filter it instead, though it is unnecessary now

Comment: That must be a huge directory.  You'll also get a match on legacy 8.3 short names.  Compare with the dir /x *.* output.  Those short names require you to filter yourself so you might as well take care of it.

Comment: First - no repro. Second, `GetFiles` returns a `string[]` array. You *don't* need to use a List, Second, if you want to use LINQ, use `EnumerateFiles` which returns an IEnumerable<string> instead of an array with all the results

Comment: @HansPassant yes, this directory has 400000+ items in it

Comment: Sure, that will do it, too many name collisions.

Comment: You can improve performance a *lot* if you use a regular expression object instead of string splitting or substring operations. A Regex is thread safe so you can create one instance and reuse it. In addition, you can use `EnumerateFiles` and `Parallel.ForEach` or `AsParallel()` to speed up filtering

Comment: With 400000 files in a single dir I would vote up everyday for an answer that uses the advice from @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: No, you want the file system to filter first so it doesn't take forever to spit out 400000 names that you have to match.  Those name collisions are still a lot less.  Best advice is to turn short name generation off with fsutil.